# changing several documents at once in word 10

Tags: windows-10

lets say several docs need address changes. is there away to update one and all will change? or is this something that needs the link method from square one? The docs are installation instructions that down the road may need part number changes which could affect several similar docs. Is there maybe a add-on for MS Word to accomplish this?

thx' george

Comment: This is not a native Word function. Please see this list here of third party solutions you might try (I have not needed to use them): https://word.tips.net/T003783_Changing_Information_in_Multiple_Documents.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two solution I can see:

- Create all the documents as Master documents and the part that changes as a
  sub-document.
  See how in the article
  [Create a Master Document in Word 2010 from Multiple Documents](https://www.howtogeek.com/73960/create-a-master-document-in-word-2010-from-multiple-documents/).
- Run a VBA macro to replace text in all the documents in a folder.

For details see the article
[How to Find and Replace Contents in Multiple Word Documents](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/find-replace-contents-multiple-word-documents/).

In case this article ever disappears, the macro is duplicated below.
The macro will put up three input-boxes, asking for: the folder, the search text
and the replacement text.

```
Sub FindAndReplaceInFolder()
  Dim objDoc As Document
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim strFolder As String
  Dim strFindText As String
  Dim strReplaceText As String

  '  Pop up input boxes for user to enter folder path, the finding and replacing texts.
  strFolder = InputBox("Enter folder path here:")
  strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\" & "*.docx", vbNormal)
  strFindText = InputBox("Enter finding text here:")
  strReplaceText = InputBox("Enter replacing text here:")

  '  Open each file in the folder to search and replace texts. Save and close the file after the action.
  While strFile <> ""
    Set objDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile)
    With objDoc
      With Selection
        .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        With Selection.Find
          .text = strFindText
          .Replacement.text = strReplaceText
          .Forward = True
          .Wrap = wdFindContinue
          .Format = False
          .MatchCase = False
          .MatchWholeWord = False
          .MatchWildcards = False
          .MatchSoundsLike = False
          .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      End With
      objDoc.Save
      objDoc.Close
      strFile = Dir()
    End With
  Wend
End Sub
```